# Obtain updated annotation coordinate (lat/lng) from callout after drag event objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, annotations, mapkit

Does anyone know how I can get the latest coordinated of my annotation after I've dragged a map annotation from a callout of the annotation? How can I access that info? Any code samples would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Zap

Answer (score 1):

I think the details you are after are covered in this blog article (which also has sample code): http://hollowout.blogspot.com/2009/07/mapkit-annotation-drag-and-drop-with.html

Comment: Note that the hollowout example has some bugs.  You need to manually update the the title value as well as subtitle, and it also is not a nice reverse-geo-server citizen.  See TOS/recommendations here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH14-SW49

Comment: (It's otherwise a very nice example -- you just have to tweak it a bit, is all.)